# Is postgres vacuum secure

Tags: postgresql, delete, vacuum, disk-structures

Postgres `delete` doesn't actually remove the record from the table file.

Once the delete is committed and the last transaction is closed, no postgres process can see the record any more, the deleted record is now liable to be `vacuum`ed.

Does vacuum (or some other system) overwrite the deleted data or is some of it left sitting in the table file?

Obviously `vacuum full` and `cluster` will both re-write the files omitting the deleted record, but I'm particularly interested if there are any details about what ordinary vacuum will or, will not, do to fields stored in the heap and TOAST files.

Answer (score 2):

Citing [the reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html):

> VACUUM FULL rewrites the entire contents of the table into a new disk
>   file with no extra space, allowing unused space to be returned to the
>   operating system

Without FULL, the database files are not even truncated, so data may still be in the files. With FULL, deleted data should be gone from the files (since they are recreated). However, data may still be in deleted parts of the underlying file system of course.

In any case, if it is important to you that data is destroyed, you must probably erase or destroy the disk.

Comment: yeah, but are the touched heap pages are re-organized during regular vacuum? is the the free space zeroed out?

Comment: erase or destroy the disk seems a little excessive when a single customer just demands their personal data be removed.

Comment: OK that's true :) I don't know for sure, but I'd assume pages are not zeroed or moved / reorganized because this technically does not make sense for the vacuum task. A garbage collection will most likely only flag space as available for re-use.